# Can I append or overwrite some bytes to an existing object in Openstack Swift?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I need to append some bytes to an existing object stored in Openstack Swift, say like a log file object and constantly append new logs to it. Is this possible?

Moreover, can I change (overwrite) some bytes (specify with offset and length) to an existing object?

Answer (score 2):

I believe ZeroVM (zerovm.org) would be perfect for doing this.

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace, who owns ZeroVM. Opinions are mine and mine alone.

Comment: It seems to me that it's a solution to another different problem, or am I just getting the wrong impression coz I haven't digged enough. Could you detail further?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to append data to an object in Swift.

ZeroVM allows you to write code that runs inside of your object storage, directly manipulating the data in the object, "living right next to the ZeroVM module", so-to-speak. Reportedly very fast.

Just an idea.

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace, who owns ZeroVM. Opinions are mine and mine alone.

Comment: Okay, this is a new and interesting idea to me. Thanks for sharing with me! I'll think this option through.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: There's no append support currently in Swift.

There's a blueprint for Swift append support: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/swift/+spec/object-append. It doesn't look very active.

user2195538 is correct. Using ZeroVM + Swift (using the [ZeroCloud](https://github.com/zerovm/zerocloud) middleware for Swift) you *could* get a performance boost on large-ish objects by sending deltas to a ZeroVM app and process them in place. Of course you still have to read/update/write the file, but you can do it in place. You don't need to pipe the entire file over the network, which could/would be costly for large files.

Disclaimer: I also work for Rackspace, and I work on ZeroVM for my day job.