# How can I append data to an Object in OpenStack Swift Object Storage?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage, watson-iot

currently want to stream realtime IoT data into OpenStack Swift, but it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549648/can-i-append-or-overwrite-some-bytes-to-an-existing-object-in-openstack-swift)
there is no support for doing this - also the [API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html) seems to support only atomic pushes.

Does anyone have any other experience or any workaround for that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Consider Dynamic Large Objects (DLO) and Static Large Object (SLO) manifests.  You can use a number of smaller objects to construct a large object via the concept of segmentation. From OpenStack Large Object Support, “Segments of the larger object are uploaded and a special manifest file is created that, when downloaded, sends all the segments concatenated as a single object.”  OpenStack Swift Object Storage does not support appending to a object per se, **however** it **does provide facility for concatenation of existing objects dynamically and statically**.

For example, you can define a filename pattern **rawdata_** and establish a DLO manifest within your Object Storage container.  Whenever you issue a get for this manifest, OpenStack swift will automatically concatenate all objects matching the defined filename pattern and return it as a single result.  This manifest object can also be loaded via the Bluemix Spark service notebooks (e.g.  swift://...) to facilitate analytics on the data.

While manifests are primarily used to support > 5 Gb objects, I've found them quite useful to slice and dice objects to construct different amounts of raw data or to handle batch processes that continually add raw data to a given container.

I've written a blog post on Object Storage manifests for the Bluemix service @ http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2016/04/14/e-pluribus-unum-creating-openstack-manifest-objects-in-ibm-bluemix-object-storage/ that may also help shed more light on their usefulness.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no support in OpenStack Swift for appending to objects.  There is this blueprint in the community: [https://blueprints.launchpad.net/swift/+spec/object-append.](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/swift/+spec/object-append)